# In the USA, is it legal for parents to take children to strip clubs?

Tags: united-states, is-x-legal

I understand there are often different laws in different states, if this is the case with this question I would appreciate answers mentioning what differences are there between states.

Comment: I'm migrating this to Law.SE as this is a "what is the law" question rather than a "why is the law" question; see https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2702/

Comment: In general it's not legal for children to be in a strip club, regardless of who took them there.

Comment: @phoog Yes, but the question is whether parents can overrule these restrictions. This is jurisdiction dependent. For alcohol consumption, in the US parents cannot overrule the age restrictions, in Germany they can and are allowed to order alcoholic drinks for the underage children in restaurants which the children would no be allowed to order on their own.

Comment: @quarague "in the US parents cannot overrule the age restrictions" is not generally correct.  Does Germany allow parents to overrule age restrictions with respect to sexual entertainment?

Comment: @quarague I would encourage you to add an answer tagged for Germany or for any other jurisdiction with which you are familiar, since the site's policy explicitly encourages this.  I answered in the context of the United States since the question is so tagged.

Comment: @phoog I don't know, my point was more that while your first comment is correct it does not fully answer the question.

Comment: The owner of such an establishment would have a say in this as well.  "We reserve the right to refuse service to anyone", and the smart owner would refuse the entry of a minor.

Comment: Like so many things in the U.S., local law would control. There wouldn't be a uniform rule across the U.S.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Findlaw has an article headlined [Strip Club Laws and the Regulation of Sexually Oriented Business](https://www.findlaw.com/smallbusiness/business-laws-and-regulations/adult-entertainment-law-zoning-and-other-regulations.html).  Among othe things, it says

> Below are some of the more common types of adult entertainment and strip club laws affecting the "manner" in which sexually-oriented establishments may operate (in addition to alcohol, which is discussed above):
>
> - Age Requirements - Most ordinances require patrons and employees to be 18 and older; 21 if alcohol is served
> - ...

I'm not going to look for the exceptions implied by the word "most," but I doubt any of them allow patrons under the age of 18.  Regardless, if the child has reached the prescribed minimum age then it is permissible under the laws regulating sexually oriented businesses for a parent to take the child to such a business.  If the child is still a minor, child protection laws may also have something to say on the matter.

Comment: What if the parent is an employee rather than a patron?  Maybe they're allowed in the back offices but can't be up front where the strippers are?  I imagine paying for daycare is not easy when you're in that line of work...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I doubt the people in that line of work have the resources to lobby politicians to make such concessions to a law.

Comment: I think NY had a ruling which allowed strip clubs to go around zoning restrictions if they allowed children with parent in.  It didn't last, but there were clubs that took advantage of it while it did.  The theory behind the ruling was this was the same as allowing minor into R-rated movies with parents because clubs only show nudity, overt sex acts.  I am not defending that position... just pointing to it.  Obviously it got struck down.

Comment: @wrod citation needed.

Comment: @phoog for a comment?  I gave you my citation.  I said "I think."  I am the source of what I think.  If you don't care and don't want to improve your answer based on that, then don't.  I gave you a possible direction for improvements to your answer.  If you don't care, why should I?

Answer (score 5):

[germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

Since Germany was mentioned in the comments:

> Jugendlichen darf der Aufenthalt in Nachtklubs und Nachtbars zu keiner
> Zeit und auch nicht in Begleitung eines Erwachsenen gestattet werden.
> Zu den Nachtklubs und Nachtbars zählen auch Angebote wie
> Stripteasebars, Animierbetriebe, Swingerklubs oder Betriebe der
> Prostitution.

Meaning, "adolescents must at no time be allowed to spend time in night clubs, even when accompanied by adults. Nightclubs includes amongst others venues such as strip clubs and places of prostitution" (or just put the paragaph above through Google translate).

Previous sections of the cited brochure make clear that adolescents in context also includes children.

It is however correct that teenagers 14 years or older may drink beer or wine if their parents are present and give permission.

(German Source: [Federal Ministry for Family Affairs, Senior Citizens, Women and Youth](https://www.bmfsfj.de/resource/blob/94070/ac4c6f22016c4ddc51b468cd2cb767bc/jugendschutz-verstaendlich-erklaert-broschuere-data.pdf))

Answer (score 2):

[new-south-wales](/questions/tagged/new-south-wales)

It is not legal for minors to be on the premises of a declared sex club under [s21D](https://legislation.nsw.gov.au/view/html/inforce/current/act-1988-025#sec.21D) of the *Summary Offences Act* 1988. The offence is committed by the operator, not by any non-operator adult who may be accompanying the minor.

However, a parent who did this may well find themselves under investigation as to whether they are a fit and proper parent under Commonwealth family law.